# No css and images loaded on home page of Mezzanine first project (hosted server)

Tags: django, dreamhost, mezzanine

I finally succeeded to install Mezzanine (3.1.4) on my hosted server (Dreamhost). Problem now is that my homepage does not show any images and does not seem to load any css files. I suspect that I have bad settings in my settings file (STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, etc). Can someone tell me how to set these variables?

Additionnally, Dreamhost requires me to set up Passenger to serve my site via Apache. I did it but I suppose that I have now to link in some way the static files of my project to the public folder Passenger created, am I right?

Mezzanine 3.1.4
Django 1.6

EDIT: project structure :

($HOME)/example.com contains

--- env.mez (my virtualenv)

--- mez (my mezzanine project)

--- passenger.wsgi

--- public (directory created by Passenger)

mez subdirectory contains (among other things):

--- manage.py

--- settings.py

--- static (directory)

settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
```

so absolute path of STATIC_ROOT is ($HOME)/example.com/mez/static and absolute path of MEDIA_ROOT is ($HOME)/example.com/mez/static/media

EDIT (solution): after reading Timmy's page, I realize that I have to collect all the static files:

```
cd mez
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After that, I have to link the static directory with the public directory:

```
ln -s ~/example.com/mez/static ~/example.com/public
```

It works now. Thank you guys!

Comment: This might help https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/

Comment: could you add your settings.py file and your project structure to help you. :)